How create many functions with one script in PGSQL
I want to ctreate many function at scheme with one sql script I'm trying the same:
begin

    create or replace function public.func1() returns text
    as $$ begin 
        return 'Test'
    end $$ language plpgsql;

    create or replace function public.func2() returns int
    as $$ begin 
        return 1
    end $$ language plpgsql;

commit;

but it creates only func1.
If you run the conditions for creating a function separately, then everything will work, but I don't want to create all the functions separately, I need one script that can be run and it will create several functions.
Postgres v13.3
To run scripts I use DBeaver.

Why is there no semicolon after the initial begin? Show the actual script you are running, and show your version of Postgres.

DBeaver is the problem. I have seen numerous similar complaints here on SO.
Add some missing semicolons and run the script in a less problematic client. Like psql or pgAdmin.
fiddle
